# How to make SASS work in Symfony3 project?

Tags: css, symfony, sass

I have a Symfony3 project and want to use SASS for my stylesheets.

I have looked up many pages and found Assetic related threads - but no "real" explanation, how to integrate SASS in a Symfony3 project.

Can't be too difficult, can it?

I would be glad to hear any hint or complete "how to" - thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a separate frontend build process using NPM for this which can handle all images, SASS/CSS, and JS with compression etc. and then add a build step to generate everything.

If you don't have NPM, follow instructions to install: https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Initialise the project by running `npm init` in your project directory.

Install some tools for compiling and compressing:

`npm install node-sass --save-dev` this compiles SASS to CSS

`npm install postcss-cli --save-dev` this processes compiled CSS

`npm install cssnano --save-dev` this minifies CSS and is used as a plugin for `postcss`

`npm install autoprefixer --save-dev` this adds moz, webkit and vendor prefixes and is used as a plugin for `postcss`

`npm install npm-run-all --save-dev` this isn't strictly necessary but allows you to group commands which is helpful as you add more steps.

Once you've got these dependencies installed, you can add your build scripts. Open `package.json` and modify the `scripts` key.

```
{
  "name": "your-project-name",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build-task:scss-compile": "node-sass --source-map true app/Resources/sass/app.sass -o web/css",
    "build-task:css-minify": "postcss web/css/app.css --use cssnano autoprefixer -d web/css",
    "build": "npm-run-all -p build-task:*"
  },
  ...
}
```

You can now run `npm run build`. `build-task:scss-compile` will compile your SASS into a single, uncompressed CSS file in the `web/css` directory which can be linked to in your templates. Then `build-task:css-minify` will compress it and add any vendor prefixes to the CSS.

You can add more build tasks as mentioned above and chain them in this way. You can also add file watchers and a watch command which will run the build scripts when any watched files are modified.

Don't forget to add `node_modules` to your `.gitignore` file.

The reason I opt for a separate process over something like Assetic and leafo/scss as outlined in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/php.html) is that Assetic filters add a lot of overhead to responses as they compress things on the fly which will slow down development considerably. It also separates concerns between application and presentation and gives you more flexibility to later build on and adapt your front end without touching your application.

**EDIT:** Here is a gist of a `package.json` file that will also copy jQuery, FontAwesome, anything in the `assets` directory including any images or fonts, compile and minify JavaScripts, after checking them for errors and create required directories if they don't already exist and a file watcher for building when files are modified:
https://gist.github.com/matt-halliday/6b9a3a015b7a87c5b165ce1a9ae19c9b

Comment: I would be interested in the JS / Img thing... If you got the time to write stuff down?! Thanks!

Comment: @MrLumbergh - I've edited and added a gist with an example file that'll do the lot: https://gist.github.com/matt-halliday/6b9a3a015b7a87c5b165ce1a9ae19c9b

Comment: @MrLumbergh also, please consider accepting this answer if it helps you...! thanks